# Why all my textures are pink if there are no missing files? Even the default cube in a brand new project

Tags: rendering, texturing, 3d-view, error

Here is the default cube with the pink error and I haven't done anything to it or the scene. I know that pink texture means that a texture is missing, but in this case there are no real missing files... Since  I opened a file with missing textures and imported it into one of my scenes this started to happen. Even when I manually open all the missing files in their materials, it won't show any of them. I created a new scene completely brand new with the default cube without adding any texture and in the second I active the render/shading mode the material turns pink. I opened the tab for scene debug and click on every option to list any missing files in any category and all of them say the same... There are no missing files. I read here that it could be a hdri missing so I changed it, but still can see the hdri background but the default cube still pink. I'm using blender 2.83

[image: In this one you can see that the material is there and linked to the object but still pink in the 3d view]

[image: In this one you can see an error I'm getting by just openning blender]

[image: Brand new scene with the default cube]

[image: Same than the other but just a few seconds later]

[image: no textures added]

[image: I don't know what's going in here]

[image: Another error in the system console]

[Here you can download the file that broke my blender...](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14NKM-XpfzK3wKS1uB4N6GLNi6sZ4Gz87?usp=drive_link)
I mean all the scenes are now corrupted. I've read all posts about pink textures and I have read Moonboots comments before in other post. Thank you for replying, guys. I'm losing my mind at this point. Something to add is that this is not happening in BlenderForArtists 2.9.3... So it's a blender issue and I believe it was that file's fault.

Comment: Hello, could you please share one of your objects?

Comment: Pink color shows on objects in case Blender can't find the image files. Make sure all textures are linked correctly to their respective image files. If it still doesn't work, please provide an example file .blend file with all the image files that need to be included as textures to be tested by others on Blender 2.83

Comment: The file tree_X12_+X1_Rock_Pack works fine on my computer, I can see the texture, same for the tree_bonus

Comment: Really? My problem started when I imported that file and I don't think I did anything else than reimporting each texture... What is going on in my blender then? As you can see in the images, it happens with every single scene now. Thank you for trying moonboots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick update to this problem and I think I can write it here since I found the source of the problem and the solution. I've investigated the errors in the system console and it was Rokoko's addon failing for some reason, so I removed it completely and restarted. Apparently that made the deal. Always be aware of the console for errors like this if you have any issue with blender, it might be the thing you less expect. Thank you moonboots and Rumen Belev for your consideration and time.